# Reduction of positive definite binary quadratic forms over congruence subgroups

Tags: reference-request, quadratic-forms

Let $\Gamma_0(N)$ be a congruence subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $Q(x,y)$ be a positive definite binary quadratic form with leading coefficient $a$ divisible by $N$. Can someone give me a reference showing how to find the matrix in $\Gamma_0(N)$ that takes $Q$ to its reduced form for $\Gamma_0(N)$? I am familiar with the algorithm for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but am having a hard time finding such a process in the literature for a general $\Gamma_0(N)$.

Comment: I could make something up that would do the job. Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I'm using SAGE to plot some Heegner points in the fundamental domain of Gamma0(N) but they do not correspond to reduced forms so are not guaranteed to lie in the fundamental domain.

Comment: Alright, I am guessing you want the final value of $a$ to be the smallest multiple of $N$ that the form represents integrally. It is then easy to force $-a < b \leq a.$ What else would you like?

Comment: take a look at pages 17-18 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603149.pdf

Comment: this looks good https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mirela/HeightsRegulators.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy, I was already using Bernard's paper but the method doesn't seem to work... The points corresponding to reduced forms given by the paper are further from the fundamental domain in the x-direction.

Comment: I wrote to someone who is deeply involved with Sage. Also found a number of possibly useful things at http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/heegner.html